# input / button rendering inconsistency in Safari

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I was playing around with flex layout for a input field with a button to the right of it. It works great in Chrome and Firefox but acts strange in Safari.
I added a code pen link to see the issue.

http://codepen.io/e-man/pen/GWpXbJ

If you view the pen in Chrome and resize the window it scales and stays together great. If you do the same in Safari you will see there is a slight gap between the submit button and the input field. Also as you scale browser smaller you will see the submit button text get cut off. 
Trying to find a way to make this consistent through all 3 browsers.

**HTML FILE**

```
<div class="container">
<form class="input-group"><input placeholder="Search For Videos" value=""><span class="input-group-btn"><button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button></span></form>
</div>
```

**Scss file**

```
$border-radius: 4px;
$search-font-size: 14px;
$search-padding: 10px;

.input-group{
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  width: 100%;

  input{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: $search-padding;
    font-size: $search-font-size;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #d2d1d1;
    border-radius: $border-radius;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    outline: none;
  }
  .input-group-btn{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-left: -1px;
    z-index: 2;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;

    .btn{
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: normal;
      text-align: center;
      white-space: nowrap;
      vertical-align: middle;
      cursor: pointer;
      outline: none;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      padding: $search-padding;
      font-size: $search-font-size;
      border-radius: $border-radius;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
      background-color: #fff;
      border-color: #ccc;
    }
  }
}
```

Screen shot from code pen showing Safari cutting text on right side of button when window is scaled to small size.
[image: Search bar image]

---

**-- UPDATE --**
Issue solved thanks to Michael_B comment about flex-shrink property.

Remove the following from **.input-group-btn**

- display: flex;
- display: -webkit-flex;

I already have these set on the parent so need in this case to set them on the children.

Then add the following to **.input-group-btn**

- -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
- flex-shrink: 0;

This fixed the issue in Safari.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
.btn { margin-left: 0; }
```

Comment: That works great for the gap issue but the second issues I mentioned is still there.  "as you scale browser smaller you will see the submit button text get cut off". 1 Down 1 to go :) Thanks

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the second issue you mentioned. But it didn't exist in my Safari. So I only addressed the problem I could reproduce.

Comment: However, consider this: flex items are set to shrink by default (`flex-shrink: 1`). Consider disable shrink perhaps. Add this to your items: `flex-shrink: 0`.

Comment: Like I said earlier, I can't reproduce the second issue. Maybe provide more details or an illustration.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I just added a screen shot to post of my code pen in Safari showing the text in button getting cut on the right side when browser window is scaled small.

Comment: That's what I figured you meant. But I'm not getting that behavior here on Safari. If `flex-shrink: 0` hasn't worked, try also `min-width: auto` or `padding: 0 15px`.

Comment: removing display: flex; from input-group-btn solved the issue of the text problem. But that in turn caused the button to over shoot a parent width. That's where your flex-shrink: 0 fixed that issue. Thanks again for the help Michael. See my updated comments in my post above.